# Google Colab hangs evaluating trivial cells

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Quite frequently Google Colab gets hung up on extremely simple cells (stuff like setting variables or defining a function--not evaluating!).

For a very explicit example, I just started a new runtime and evaluated cell 1 (below). Then colab got hung on evaluating cell 2:

Cell 1 (ran):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Cell 2 (stopped colab):

```
delta_t = .01
```

This appears to have nothing to do with how many cells have been evaluated -- sometimes it gets hung up on the first cell.

This is obviously quite annoying as the only solution is to restart the entire runtime.

However I have noticed that I can sometimes copy the code to a new cell, and then evaluate it there. I.e. while the first cell is still trying to evaluate, I can run the *same* code in a different cell and have it successfully complete.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Comment: Does this behavior reproduce for you reliably? (I just tried your example in Chrome 81.0.4044.138 and it worked as expected.) Are there errors logged to the Javascript console? Does this behavior reproduce in an incognito window with all extensions disabled?

Comment: No, this is not reliable. However, it does seem like once any cell gets caught, even if I restart the runtime another cell is likely to fail. (I.e. it seems like the probability of failing again increases once its happened once.)

Comment: I am using Safari Version 13.1 (14609.1.20.111.8) but has happened on previous versions of Safari as well.

Comment: I think the most interesting part of the problem is the last thing I mentioned -- that I can copy and paste code into a new window and successfully run it *simultaneous* with the failing cell. This suggests that it is somehow a failure on the cell level.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works just fine, and it's not supposed to produce any error.
Of course, Google Colab has its limitations, but setting variables and defining a function are not one of them.

Put in mind that Colab Notebooks run by connecting to virtual machines that have maximum lifetimes that can be as much as 12 hours. Notebooks will also disconnect from VMs when left idle for too long. Maximum VM lifetime and idle timeout behavior may vary over time, or based on your usage.

In case of having internet connection problems in your client machine, you may get hung up too.

You can check more about Google Colab limitations here https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits

Comment: This failure often occurs within minutes of starting a new runtime. I do not think it is correlated with leaving an environment open for a long period, although I have not explicitly tried this. (Indeed, if I can just make it work for a reasonable amount of time, say an hour, I would be perfectly happy. The problem is that it happens so frequently and unpredictably).

Comment: Can you extract logs using runtime>View runtime logs?